# Laravel inserting data as many-to-many and getting error

Tags: php, laravel

In my application design i each category should be have one or multiple user which i should associate them together, this middle category should be have `category_id` referenced with `categories` table and `user_id` referenced with `users` table. now i have this migration files:

User:

```php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable()->constrained();

    $table->boolean('active')->default(0); //activating account in register
    $table->string('name')->nullable();
    $table->string('family')->nullable();
    $table->string('username')->unique();
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->index()->nullable();
    $table->string('password');

    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->softDeletes();
    
    $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
    $table->timestamp('updated_at')->useCurrent();
});
```

categories:

```php
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
    $table->string('title');
    
    $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
    $table->timestamp('updated_at')->useCurrent();
});
```

user_category:

```php
Schema::create('user_category', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->primary(
        [
            'category_id',
            'user_id'
        ]
    );
});
```

running `migrate` command work fine and i don't get any error, now i want to create a category and then created category should be referenced with `user_category` table with `attach`:

```php
$category = \App\Models\Category::create(
    [
        'title' => 'php',
    ]
);
$category->owner()->attach(
    [
        'user_id' => 1
    ]
);
```

here i get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'category_user_id' in 'field list'
   (SQL: insert into `user_category` 
      (`category_id`, `category_user_id`) values (4, 1))
```

my `Models`:

category:

```php
public function owner(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(CategoryUser::class );
}
```

user_category:

```php
public function category(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel's naming convention for pivot tables is snake_cased model names in alphabetical order separated by an underscore.

So if you are to follow the conventions, the `user_category` table should be `category_user` instead.

Also, the relationships should be in plural form for many-to-many relations.

```php
// Category model
public function users(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}

// User model
public function categories(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
```

If you are however deviating from the conventions, you can also set it up by customizing the relationships like so:

```php
// Category model
public function owner(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_category', 'category_id', 'user_id');
}

// User model
public function category(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'user_category', 'user_id', 'category_id');
}
```

Comment: @p-k-tharindu thanks so much, can you explain last part of your code? my meant is customizing relationships, in Category model why you used `user_id` as `relatedPivotKey` and you used `category_id` same as in `user` model

Comment: Because that's what you have named your foreign keys in the `user_category` pivot table. It's all in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many